# Prove $\sin(1)\sin(2)\sin(3)\cdots\sin(n)$ converges as $n\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Does this sequence $\sin(1)\sin(2)\cdots\sin(n)$ converge to 0? Or does it converge at all?

Comment: It converges to 0 because $n$ will be arbitrarily close to a multiple of $\pi$ infinitely often

Comment: Welcome to math.se. See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) formatting guide.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch $\pi$ being irrational, does any of the $sin(n)$ has $n$ an exact multiple of $\pi$ (even though it goes from $1$ to $\infty$)?

Comment: @RingØ No - for the reason that $\pi$ is irrational.  Hence "arbitrarily close to" rather than "is"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It converges to $0$ because

- every term is between $-1$ and $1$
- and at least one in every three terms has an absolute value below $\sin(\frac \pi 2\pm\frac12) \approx 0.8776$
- so the absolute value of the product of $n$ terms will be below $0.8776^{n/3}$ for $n \ge 3$,
- and that converges to $0$ as $n$ increases

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on @MaximilianJanisch's comment, for infinitely many integers $q>0$ there is an integer $p>0$ with $\left|\frac{p}{q}-\pi\right|<\frac{\sqrt{5}}{q^2}$, whence$$|\sin p|=\left|\sin\left[q\left(\frac{p}{q}-\pi\right)\right]\right|<\frac{\sqrt{5}}{q}.$$Such sines ensures the desired infinite product is $0$.